# enabling jest cache in CI servers

Tags: jestjs

As I understand Jest test execution gets faster when we run along with the cache build over the previous runs. In out project we are able to realize that benefit when we run our test in local. We are planing to do the same in the CI server also.

Is it a good practice to enable cache for the jest test execution in the CI server, so they are available across the subsequent builds.
What are the things that we would have to lookout for when enabling cache.
Any personal experience on the same will be great

Comment: This is a good question. I wonder that if in CI/CD it will only likely run once (as long as all tests pass first time and they don't need to be re-run). Whereas, when running locally, the cache is stored locally to and is used in subsequent runs (?)

Comment: Have you been able to accomplish this? I'm looking at changing cacheDirectory in the jest.config.ts and use cache@2 (for Azure) to get that done, but I'm not having much luck.

Comment: I tried with GitHub actions, and the result is marginal.  I am not sure if I have missed anything.